# localForage using WebSQL web IndexedDB available

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, indexeddb, localforage

I am building a Cordova app with the Ionic Framework. I am using [angular-localForage](https://github.com/ocombe/angular-localForage) as the local database for the app's persistent storage.

While developing, I am testing my app using Google Chrome 45.0.2454.85 m on Windows 10. angular-localForage is at version 1.2.3 and localForage is version 1.2.4.

I can set and retrieve data no problem. To set data I am using:

```
$localForage.setItem(myKey, myData).then(myCallbackFunction);
```

According to the [docs](https://github.com/mozilla/localForage), localForage should use IndexedDB if it's available and fall back to WebSQL for browsers where it is not available. I can see from looking at Resources in Chrome Developer tools that it is storing my data in WebSQL.

If I put this code in my controller I get a message saying IndexedDB is available:

```
if (!window.indexedDB) {
    window.alert("Your browser doesn't support a stable version of IndexedDB. Such and such feature will not be available.");
} else {
    window.alert("IndexedDB available.");
}
```

My question is, why is it using WebSQL in Chrome when I have IndexedDB available?

Comment: May be check your localforage config if set driver is  localforage.INDEXEDDB

Comment: Check how they testing for support of IndexedDB, it is not just window.indexedDB. https://github.com/mozilla/localForage/blob/master/src/localforage.js#L57

Comment: Cheers for the reply. Can't see anything in the code that would make it not work in Chrome though...

Answer (score 5):

The problem is actually quite sneaky.

TLDR; Apple's UIWebView doesn't support indexedDB. Turn off Chrome's iOS emulator to see indexedDB working.

What's happening is that I'm assuming you're emulating an iPhone with Chrome dev tools. Well, this spoofing is actually really effective because `localForage` will now emit an error if you configured it to exclusively use indexedDB.

If you want to have a moment of profound ennui and see indexedDB in action... turn off emulation so that you're using Chrome's own user-agent. It'll work then.

Source: I had to deal with this nonsense myself. It was a really bad developer experience. HAH.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that websql is taken as first choice since it exists longer than the indexeddb api and chrome was pushing websql earlier than indexeddb. Since chrome still supports websql it takes websql before indexeddb.

Comment: Well, localForage default priority is IndexedDB, try fallback to websql, or fallback to the localStorage.

Comment: No. The OP was likely spoofing Mobile Safari using Chrome's Devtools. So `localForage` technically was correct in falling back to WebSQL despite him setting the driver priority (`localForage.setDriver()`).